# Power calculation for AC signal at the rectifier input

Tags: rectifier

I am working on the design of rectifier using MOS in Cadence ADE. The AC signal amplitude is 415 mV at a frequency of 865 MHz. The current is 14.5 mA. Now, the dDC voltage is 400 mV and the load current of 2 uA. Can you please let me know how to calculate the efficiency? PCE is the DC output power / ac input power. How should I calculate the ac input power? The values which I had mentioned above are not the RMS values.

Comment: Maybe link to a circuit so we can see what you are doing. Also, if not RMS voltages, what are they?

Comment: Voltage is the amplitude of the voltage source. current is the amplitude of the ac current, which generated from the source. I plotted the ac current waveform by clicking on the source voltage node in cadence.

Comment: I am unable to post the schematics or the block diagram :-(

Comment: I've just up-voted you and hopefully someone else will to take you over a reputation of 10. This allows you to post. Otherwise can you link to the circuit and I or someone else will post it for you?

Comment: The circuit is from IEEE paper titled "A High-Efficiency CMOS Rectifier for Low-Power RFID Tags" IEEE RFID 2010 paper.

Comment: Moreover, my question is not related to any specific circuit. In general, how should I calculate the PCE for rectifier. If I am giving any sinusoidal input voltage, then how should I calculate the power? I am using Cadence spectre ADE - virtuoso.

Comment: Do you want a single half wave rectifier or a full bridge rectifier circuit? Power out is power in minus losses in the diode and that is easy but translating this to losses in a diode at 815MHz with the extremely low voltages you specify is not going to help you because at 415mV RMS ac you'll hardly get anything through a diode.